# Is it normal to have this much difficulty with the problems in Spivak's Calculus?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, soft-question

So I'm a senior in high school going through Spivak's Calculus. I've made it up to chapter 3 with a lot of difficulty and only being able to solve less than half of the problems. If I can't prove some theorem on my own I can usually understand the proof although sometimes it takes whole days to feel like I'm starting to wrap my head around it. My biggest problem is that it seems like I never know where to begin. Is this something that will just come with time? For example a problem I'm currently stuck on is showing that for each $n$ there is a polynomial function of degree $n$ with $n$ roots. I have already proven that if $f$ is a polynomial function of degree $n$ , then $f$ has at most $n$ roots. I assume this proof builds on that one. I just don't know where to start.

Update: Okay so funny enough I think a proof just came to me but I want to make sure it's correct. So my proof is

> There is a polynomial of degree $n=1$ with exactly one root. Assume $g$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ with $k$ roots, then $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $k+1$ with $k+1$ roots. Therefore for each $n$ there is a polynomial function of degree $n$ with $n$ roots.

Is this proof valid?

Comment: Spivak is pretty hard, no question. I don't think anybody finds it easy. For this particular question, though, ...can you construct a polynomial of degree $n$ with roots at, say, $1,2,3,\cdots, n$?

Comment: About your math problem: Fix $n$ distinct numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ and consider the polynomial $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_n)$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch wow, you seem to be one of those child prodigies. i hope you have a great math career. just always work hard and don't get cocky enough to think you don't need to. work as much as possible

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks for the tip and the nice words! :)

Comment: @mathworker21 ok fair enough. Im not sure why I have this much trouble with proofs. I breezed through the first half of stewarts calculus so i figured i would be ready for this and ive excelled in high school level math. So its not normal to have this much trouble with that problem even though spivak is my introduction to proofs?

Comment: @RyanSchardine, it's perfectly normal to have this much trouble if Spivak is your introduction to proofs. This kind of precise/rigorous reasoning takes some getting used to, and although it may come more easily to some people than to others, please do not let this discourage you, especially if you enjoy the subject.

Comment: Please make a new post (with the Ask Question button) to ask about the specific problem you are trying to solve.  It kind of messes things up if you derail one question to ask a new one.  And definitely don't use the answer space for updates or new questions.

Comment: @NateEldredge ok im brand new to this website so was unaware of the restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

#### My solution

With just implicit induction, you could simply take the polynomial $f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)\dotsm(x-n)$. If you have already proved that the degree of a product is the sum of the degrees and that $r$ is a root of $p(x)q(x)$ if and only if it is either a root of $p$ or a root of $q$, then you're done.

#### Your attempt

It depends on what you mean by “$n$ roots”. I believe that Spivak means *$n$ distinct roots*, otherwise simply $x^n$ would be an answer.

Your idea is good, but lacks a detail. OK, the polynomial $x$ has degree $1$ and $1$ root. Suppose that we're able to find a polynomial $g$ of degree $n$, having $n$ (distinct) roots $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n$. Then take $a_{n+1}=\max\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}+1$ and the polynomial $f(x)=(x-a_{n+1})g(x)$ has degree $n+1$ and $n+1$ distinct roots.

#### Comment

The strange choice of $a_{n+1}$ ensures it is distinct from the given roots. In other contexts, the statement would be false: over the two-element field, for instance, no polynomial of degree $n>2$ can have $n$ distinct roots.

Comment: Okay thank you for the response. I actually went back and did exactly that right after i made the original proof.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Okay so funny enough i think a proof just came to me but i want to make sure it's correct. So my proof is There is a polynomial of degree $n=1$ with exactly one root. Assume $g$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ with $k$ roots, then $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $k+1$ with $k+1$ roots. Therefore for each $n$ there is a polynomial function of degree $n$ with $n$ roots. Is this proof valid?

Comment: it depends what "$n$ roots" means. does it mean $n$ distinct roots? or $n$ roots counting multiplicity? if it means the latter, then literally any degree $n$ polynomial will work. if it means the former, then you're proof is wrong, but will work if you choose $a$ more wisely.

Comment: @mathworker21 im unsure which it means but does saying g(x) has roots at a_1,...,a_k make this work? And then have f(x)=(x-a_k+1)g(x).

Comment: "if it means the former, then you're proof is wrong, but will work if you choose $a$ more wisely."

Comment: @mathworker21 im sorry im unsure what you mean by that. Was what i just changed not enough? Because i fail to see how its not.

Comment: Ryan, all you have to do to make your proof work is to choose your $a$ to be different from all the roots of $g$.

Comment: @tonyk ok thank you thats what i tried to show i was doing there but i probably could have just stated a doesnt equal all the roots of g.

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "probably could have"?

Comment: I fixed the problem in an earlier comment but could have fixed it in a slightly simpler way. That's all i meant.